# BSc: double thesis or thesis with multiple topics?

Tags: thesis

I have been working on two research projects at different departments during my BSc. One of them yielded a conference paper and the other one was initially decided to be my final thesis topic. The latter one is also going well and we are planning to make a journal publication on it. I have to write my final thesis next semester and I am wondering whether I should make two separate theses for two research topics or involve them inside a single thesis.

I appreciate your opinion!

Comment: Why would you write 2 theses or 1 thesis with 2 topics? One good thesis with one topic should do it? Everything else can be published via a conference and/or journal?

Comment: This makes sense. I think I will do so. Thanks!

Comment: Some mentors like stuffed theses. I had good success in first convincing my other mentor to limit the thesis to one subject, then telling the first one that we had discussed it and both agreed that the thesis should be made short and concise. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make *one* good story about the combination of the two, that's what *could* make your thesis outstanding. But it's also going to be a lot more work, and if it doesn't work out, you just wasted a lot of time.

If you're not convinced you can and really want to pull this, go and ditch one of the two subjects. It's a lot less hassle for both you and your prof, you'll get a good grade, and that's it.

As was mentioned in the comments, it's already published, so there is no need to publish it *again*, and in a thesis, which so few people will read ever again.